# How does accepting a non-faculty staff job affect faculty applications?

Tags: career-path, job-search, interview, early-career

I am currently employed as a postdoc. I recently received an offer for a non-faculty online instructional staff position while simultaneously applying for several faculty (tenure track and non-tenure track) and academic research positions. I was told that accepting the staff position would reduce or even eliminate my chances of being considered and/or accepted for tenure track positions, as search committees would view me as not fully committed to the R1 TT career path. Is it possible to accept the instructional staff position while also remaining in the running for these other positions? Or is this advice correct, and accepting the instructional staff position would disqualify me from being considered for faculty and/or research positions?

Comment: The timing is unclear. When does your postdoc position end? Are you considering taking the staff position in addition to the postdoc, or to resign your postdoc position and take the staff position, or to finish out the postdoc and then take the staff position? And how would this timeline fit in with the TT jobs you're applying for? I'd say that if the staff position is only a temporary thing to tide you over for a semester while you're waiting for the outcomes of your TT applications, then it's unlikely to hurt your chances. If it's for a longer term, then @R1NaNo's advice seems applicable.

Comment: The last scenario is correct. My postdoc is unsustainable and I am looking for options that could sustain me until hearing my application results, while also potentially opening up other career paths should they be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 11):

This is going to be field/environment/culture dependent... but in general the advice you got is not wrong.

It's just hard to land any TT job at an R1, and has been for quite a while. Each posting can generate hundreds of applications. Among them are typically people who are currently postdocs at a top 25, or national lab research staff, or very notable industry R&D (think the big companies, Google, Intel, etc..). There is a very real halo effect, part of which is warranted. If you want to build departmental excellence, you bring in people who are being trained at the very top.

Having a random staff job is unfortunately going to put you at a disadvantage compared to those other applicants. It doesn't mean it will completely disqualify you, but the disadvantage is real.

Comment: My field is education. I would like to be prepared for multiple career paths, but would prefer to avoid closing the tenure track faculty door prematurely or unnecessarily.

Comment: Upvoted. It's not just a halo effect, there's also a very real effect where the postdocs OP will be competing with have jobs that pay them to do research (and give them the time to do it), whereas the staff position doesn't. So those postdocs will be at a real advantage in terms of their research output. But I agree it's likely there's a halo effect as well. And I agree that having a staff position is only one factor among many and not necessarily disqualifying.

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of how the "commitment" to an R1 tenure track career is viewed, the main problem with moving from instructional staff to faculty/research positions is the gap that an instructional staff position is likely to leave in your publication history, as instructional/non-faculty/non-tenure track is unlikely to allow many, if any, research/publication opportunities, and that is a huge factor in hiring for most R1 tenure track positions.

Comment: The time employed as instructional staff would be less than 8 months until potential hire dates, my publication count is already relatively high, and I would likely have at least 1-2 current publications in the year I could be hired as tenure track. Would any of these factors improve my competitiveness?

Comment: So the position in question is more to fill your time until August/September or so, when presumably you would start one of these other positions? In that case, I don't think it would be a particularly huge problem. If you were looking at more than a year or so it likely would be a problem, but as a temporary measure you can cast it as gaining more teaching experience, which might even help some of your applications a bit (though probably only if the R1 institutes you're applying to actually care about the teaching component that comes with a lot of those R1 positions.)